# how to use Apache webserver when both IIS and Apache are installed on the same computer

Tags: apache-2.2, iis-7

I have IIS 7 installed on my computer. I installed WAMP on this system but now I am not able to use websites on Apache.

I tried using -

> iisreset stop

but that threw an error -

> The RPC server is unavailable.

how can I stop IIS 7 so that I can use my websites on Apache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Using a command line**
>
> 1. Open an elevated command-line window.
> 2. At the command prompt, type **net stop WAS** and press ENTER; type **Y** and
>      then press ENTER to also stop W3SVC.
> 3. To restart the Web server, type **net start W3SVC** and press ENTER to
>      start both WAS and W3SVC.

Source : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732317(WS.10).aspx

Comment: I used these commands, but now when I try to access http://localhost/ I get a "Unable to connect" error message.

Comment: did you start apache after you used them? this command turns off IIS7, it doesn't start apache.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have changed the ports the web servers run on you cannot, by default they both run on Port 80.
Head into IIS and change the binding to port 81 instead of 80. This will allow apache to run, whilst attempting to access website via IIS they will need to end with :81

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have not done this before, could you tell me how to change the port in IIS 7. The OS is Windows server 2008, if that helps.

Comment: Here you go: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/149605

Comment: Well thanks, but that's the problem. I do not have any default website when I open inetmgr.

Answer (score 1):

You can use XAMPP, very easy to install an let you start your apache as service.

If you are looking for IIS to listen port 80 and apache on port 81, also you have to change apache SSL port, because IIS use 443.

If you want to use both on port 80, you can add to your Windows one virtual IP to the Local Conection, under TCP/IP Properties.

You will use your default static IP for IIS and the apache will use the virtual IP.
Then, add some entries on your c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts, like:

> iis.local  192.168.x.x
>   apache.local        192.168.x.y

Try to start both services.
Ask me if you have further questions.
Regards,